# URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] nd>

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Run the following coding and encountered the error message.

```
 import numpy as np
 import pickle, gzip, urllib.request, json
 import os.path

 if not os.path.isfile('mnist.pkl.gz'):
     # Load the dataset
     urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://deeplearning.net/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz", 'mnist.pkl.gz')

 with gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb') as f:
     train_set, valid_set, test_set = pickle.load(f, encoding='latinl')

 train_X, train_y = train_set
 valid_X, valid_y = valid_set
 test_X, test_y = test_set

 print(train_X.shape, train_y.shape)
 print(valid_X.shape, valid_y.shape)
 print(test_X.shape, test_y.shape)
 print(train_X.dtype, train_y.dtype)
 print(train_X[9][300], train_y[9])
 print(np.min(train_y), np.max(train_y))
```

How to resolve the following error message:
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:1348, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
1347 try:
-> 1348     h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
1349               encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
1350 except OSError as err: # timeout error

```
 File ~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1283, in HTTPConnection.request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
    1282 """Send a complete request to the server."""
 -> 1283 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

 File ~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1329, in HTTPConnection._send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
    1328     body = _encode(body, 'body')
 -> 1329 self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

 File ~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1278, in HTTPConnection.endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
    1277     raise CannotSendHeader()
 -> 1278 self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

 File ~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1038, in HTTPConnection._send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
    1037 del self._buffer[:]
 -> 1038 self.send(msg)
    1040 if message_body is not None:
    1041 
    1042     # create a consistent interface to message_body

 File ~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:976, in HTTPConnection.send(self, data)
     975 if self.auto_open:
 --> 976     self.connect()
     977 else:

 File ~\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:942, in HTTPConnection.connect(self)
     941 sys.audit("http.client.connect", self, self.host, self.port)
 --> 942 self.sock = self._create_connection(
     943     (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
     944 # Might fail in OSs that don't implement TCP_NODELAY

 File ~\anaconda3\lib\socket.py:845, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
     844 try:
 --> 845     raise err
     846 finally:
     847     # Break explicitly a reference cycle

 File ~\anaconda3\lib\socket.py:833, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
     832     sock.bind(source_address)
 --> 833 sock.connect(sa)
     834 # Break explicitly a reference cycle

 TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 Cell In[8], line 7
       3 import os.path
       5 if not os.path.isfile('mnist.pkl.gz'):
       6     # Load the dataset
 ----> 7     urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://deeplearning.net/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz", 'mnist.pkl.gz')
       9 with gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb') as f:
      10     train_set, valid_set, test_set = pickle.load(f, encoding='latinl')

 File ~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:241, in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
     224 """
     225 Retrieve a URL into a temporary location on disk.
     226
```

(...)
237 data file as well as the resulting HTTPMessage object.
238 """
239 url_type, path = _splittype(url)
--> 241 with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
242     headers = fp.info()
244     # Just return the local path and the "headers" for file://
245     # URLs. No sense in performing a copy unless requested.

```
 File ~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:216, in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
     214 else:
     215     opener = _opener
 --> 216 return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

 File ~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:519, in OpenerDirector.open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
     516     req = meth(req)
     518 sys.audit('urllib.Request', req.full_url, req.data, req.headers, req.get_method())
 --> 519 response = self._open(req, data)
     521 # post-process response
     522 meth_name = protocol+"_response"

 File ~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:536, in OpenerDirector._open(self, req, data)
     533     return result
     535 protocol = req.type
 --> 536 result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
     537                           '_open', req)
     538 if result:
     539     return result

 File ~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:496, in OpenerDirector._call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
     494 for handler in handlers:
     495     func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
 --> 496     result = func(*args)
     497     if result is not None:
     498         return result

 File ~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:1377, in HTTPHandler.http_open(self, req)
    1376 def http_open(self, req):
 -> 1377     return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)

 File ~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:1351, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
    1348         h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
    1349                   encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
    1350     except OSError as err: # timeout error
 -> 1351         raise URLError(err)
    1352     r = h.getresponse()
    1353 except:

 URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

Comment: http://deeplearning.net/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz - does this page exist? Page not found...

Comment: It seems that page - deeplearning.net/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz does not exist. But I found the file from github and downloaded to use. The previous error message seems to be resolved. But new error exist - LookupError: unknown encoding: latinl

Comment: When encoding: latinl is changed to latin1, LookupError is resolved.